# Sqlite3 median with group by on 2 columns offset sub query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 and am trying to get the median value of different groups. I am currently using the following query

```
with data as (
select
t1.Name,
t1.Direction,
t1.Time a,
t2.Time b
from
cart t1 join cart t2 on t1.Time < t2.Time and t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Direction = t2.Direction)
select Name, Direction, (a+b)/2.0 val from data order by Name, Direction, val
```

Which outputs the following:

```
"Name"  "Direction" "val"
"asdf"  "w"         "1.5"
"asdf"  "w"         "2.0"
"asdf"  "w"         "2.5"
"asdf"  "z"         "3.5"
"asdf"  "z"         "4.0"
"asdf"  "z"         "4.5"
"fdas"  "w"         "7.5"
"fdas"  "w"         "8.0"
"fdas"  "w"         "8.5"
"fdas"  "z"         "5.5"
"fdas"  "z"         "6.0"
"fdas"  "z"         "6.5"
```

From this point I would like to find the median value of all unique Name/Direction pairs.

Expected result:

```
Name Direction Val
asdf w         2.0
asdf z         4.0
fdas w         8.0
fdas z         6.0
```

Or if it would make it easier Name and Direction can also be joined into a single unique ID with the following output

```
Name   Val
asdfw  2.0
asdfz  4.0
fdasw  8.0
fdasz  6.0
```

The original table data is as follows:

```
"Name"  "Direction" "Time"
"fdas"  "w" "8"
"fdas"  "w" "9"
"fdas"  "w" "7"
"fdas"  "z" "7"
"fdas"  "z" "6"
"fdas"  "z" "5"
"asdf"  "z" "5"
"asdf"  "z" "4"
"asdf"  "z" "3"
"asdf"  "w" "3"
"asdf"  "w" "2"
"asdf"  "w" "1"
```

### Update

I've gotten a little closer with the following query. The only issue left is finding the required offset query. Currently I have it hard coded with the following `offset 3`, but would need to get the center row. I've tried `(select idx from calcs where data2.Name = calcs.Name and data2.Direction = calcs.Direction)`, but then I get this error `no such table: calcs: with data2`.

```
with data2 as (
with data as (
select
t1.Name,
t1.Direction,
t1.Time a,
t2.Time b
from
cart t1 join cart t2 on t1.Time < t2.Time and t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Direction = t2.Direction)
select Name, Direction, (a+b)/2.0 c from data order by Name, Direction, c
) select
    Name,
    Direction,
    (select c from
        (select c from data2 where data2.Name = calcs.Name and data2.Direction = calcs.Direction
            order by c
            limit 1
            offset 2 ) subset
    order by subset.c) tt
from
(select Name, Direction, round(COUNT(*)/2.0) idx from data2 group by Name, Direction) calcs
```

Answer (score 0):

use another sub-query

```
with data as (
select
t1.Name,
t1.Direction,
t1.Time a,
t2.Time b
from
cart t1 join cart t2 
on t1.Time < t2.Time and t1.Name = t2.Name 
and t1.Direction = t2.Direction
),
data2 as 
  (
 select Name, Direction, 
 (a+b)/2.0 as val 
 from data 
 order by Name, Direction, val
  ) select Name,Direction,avg(val) as mdval from data2 group by 
  Name,Direction
```

Or just use aggregation  in your 2nd query

```
with data as (
select
t1.Name,
t1.Direction,
t1.Time a,
t2.Time b
from
cart t1 join cart t2 on t1.Time < t2.Time and t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Direction = t2.Direction
)
select Name, Direction, avg((a+b)/2.0) as val
from data group by Name, Direction
order by Name, Direction, val
```

Comment: This returns the calculated average (mean), I'm looking for the median, in this case, it is the same, but this is a trivial example.